# QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting

Tags: c++, json, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm having issues with my code and I need you to give me a hand please. I'm getting:

```
step 1
step 2
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_select_next_proto
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
step 3
step 4
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
step 3
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
ASSERT: "a && i >= 0 && i < (int)a->length" in file json\qjsonarray.cpp, line 527
QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting
```

I'm just ignoring QSslSocket errors cause I know it's due to https requests but I'm not using it. Here is my code:

TheMovieDB.cpp

```
TheMovieDB::TheMovieDB(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)
{
    qDebug()<<"step 1";
    t_api_key="?api_key=******************";
    t_api_url="http://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
    t_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
    t_resultID=0;
}    

void TheMovieDB::search(const QString &title)
{
    qDebug()<<"step 2";
    t_title=GeneralFunctions::prepareString(title); //on normalise la chaîne (retire les accents)
    t_api_query= t_api_url + "search/movie" + t_api_key + "&language=fr&query=" + title;
    t_manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(t_api_query)));
    QObject::connect(t_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(readTitleSearch(QNetworkReply *)));
}

void TheMovieDB::readTitleSearch(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug()<<"step 3";
    QString source = reply->readAll();
    QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(source.toUtf8());
    QJsonObject jsonObj = document.object();
    QJsonArray obj = jsonObj["results"].toArray();
    QDate date;

    int distance=GeneralFunctions::distanceDL(t_title , obj[0].toObject()["title"].toString());
    t_resultID=obj[0].toObject()["id"].toInt();
    int distanceToBeCompared=0;

    for(int i = 1; i < obj.count(); i++){
        if(date.fromString(obj[i].toObject()["release_date"].toString(), "yyyy-MM-dd") < QDate::currentDate())
        {
            distanceToBeCompared=GeneralFunctions::distanceDL(t_title , obj[i].toObject()["title"].toString());
            if(distance > distanceToBeCompared)
            {
                distance=distanceToBeCompared;
                t_resultID=obj[i].toObject()["id"].toInt();
            }
        }
    }

    searchID(t_resultID);
}

void TheMovieDB::searchID(const int &id)
{
    qDebug()<<"step 4";
    t_api_query=t_api_url+"movie/"+QString::number(id)+t_api_key+"&language=fr";
    t_manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(t_api_query)));
    QObject::connect(t_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(readIDSearch(QNetworkReply *)));
}


void TheMovieDB::readIDSearch(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug()<<"step 5";

    /* some code */

    emit idSearchDone();
}
```

TheMovieDB.h

```
class TheMovieDB:public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TheMovieDB(QWidget *parent=0);
    void search(const QString &title);
    QMap<QString, QVariant> t_infosList;
    void searchID(const int &id);

private:
    QString t_title;
    QString t_api_url;
    QString t_api_key;
    QString t_api_query;
    int t_resultID;
    QString t_picturePath;
    QNetworkAccessManager* t_manager;

public slots:
    void readTitleSearch(QNetworkReply *reply);
    void readIDSearch(QNetworkReply *reply);    

signals:
    void idSearchDone();

};
```

Main.cpp

```
TheMovieDB tmdb;
tmdb.search("avatar");
```

I should have step 1,2,3,4,5. But I'm getting a second step 3 instead of step 5. Thank you for your help. The app is bugging when I'm launching it.

Comment: You are passing the *very same* signal (`finished(QNetworkReply *)`) to two different slots and the first is probably called in place of the second, as you expected. Try to `disconnect` from `readTitleSearch` before connecting to `readIDSearch`. Revisiting the code would be a good idea.

Comment: I have no way else to do it. Or creating 2 QNetworkAccessManager maybe?

Comment: Well then, `disconnect` before connecting. That would work.

Comment: Ok I've tried with 2 QNetworkAccessManager. I'm getting the step 5. But then I'm getting "step 3" and ASSERT: "a && i >= 0 && i < (int)a->length" in file json\qjsonarray.cpp, line 527
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting

Comment: nvm, It's not working in "some code". I think it's the same kind of problem as I'm using another QNetworkAccessManager later. How am I supposed to disconnect it?

Comment: Either `disconnect` the signal before reconnecting it for the next slot or define a unique slot which handles all the replies. None of the two approaches is feasable?

Comment: Ok it's working now. I'm adding the solution to my post. Thanks! :)

Comment: NOPE. Just post it as a solution and accept it. That's the way to go here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to disconnect the previous signal finished from readTitleSearch before connecting it again. To do it, add:

```
t_manager->disconnect(t_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(readTitleSearch(QNetworkReply *)));
```

Before using it again.